# Connecting iPhone to hotel's ethernet network

Tags: network, iphone

I am going on holiday tomorrow and the hotel I am staying in does not have wireless internet access in the bedrooms (awful oversight I know!).  They do however have ethernet points in each room.  I will only be taking my iPhone with me on this trip which obviously doesn't have an ethernet port.  However I do have a Netgear DG834PN modem-router which I can take with me.

I had a thought that I could put the router in bridged mode and use it as a wireless access point so that my iPhone can utilise the ethernet network.  Does this sound correct?  If I understand bridging correctly, this will mean that I won't need to assign an IP address to my router as it will take the one handed out by the DHCP server in the hotel.

Is any of this at all correct?  If not, do I have any options or am I stuck?

Comment: Super User is not for questions about mobile devices as per the [FAQ](http://superuser.com/faq).

Answer (score 1):

Yes, this could work. It's an odd solution, but allowing your router to be a bridge, then presenting a wireless SSID to your iPhone is a way to make this work. Perhaps the hotel assumed guests would bring laptop computers, thus the hard-wired ethernet ports...

Comment: Excellent! I have changed the mode of the router to be modem only (rather than modem+router.  The only issue I anticipate with this is that it seems I still need to enter an IP address for the router.  This could be fairly difficult if I can't get the information from the hotel.  Should I expect to be able to just plug the router in and get an IP address?  Should I clear the address on the router?

Comment: For this exact reason I carry an airport express in my bag. Small and will easily bridge wired to wireless.

Comment: Your router asks your to set an IP for it in bridge mode because you still need an IP to connect to the management interface. You can assign it any private address that is rarely used, e.g. in the 172.16.0.0/12 range (172.16.0.0 - 172.31.255.255) and remember to manually set your iPhone to the same subnet if you want to configure your router.

Comment: I thought this might be the case. I guess I'll have to find out which IP range the hotel is using? If they use 192.168... then I surely can't use an IP of 172.16... can I?

Answer (score 0):

before you go, write down the MAC address of a PC. Tell your router to display the MAC address of the PC on the WAN port. Some Hotels do check and disallow the MAC of home routers.

otherwise this is a good idea.

Answer (score 0):

Ignore the WAN port altogether and connect your in-room Ethernet to one of the LAN ports. Be sure to disable DHCP on the LAN side so that your router doesn't attempt to provide invalid addresses to your devices, or to other guests.

No need for any complicated modes. Any home wireless router can be used this way. In fact, that's how I set up my wireless, since I use a separate dedicated router.